# Performance Improvement Tips for ForEach loop in C#?

Tags: c#, performance, optimization

I need to optimize the below `foreach` loop. The foreach loop is taken more time to get the unique items.

1. Instead can the `FilterItems` be converted into a list collection. If so how to do it. Then i will take unique items easily from it.
2. The problem arises when i have 5,00,000 items in FilterItems.

Please suggest some ways to optimize the below code:

```
int i = 0; 
List<object> order = new List<object>();
List<object> unique = new List<object>();
// FilterItems IS A COLLECTION OF RECORDS. CAN THIS BE CONVERTED TO A LIST COLLECTION DIRECTLY, SO THAT I CAN TAKE THE UNIQUE ITEMS FROM IT.
foreach (Record rec in FilterItems)
{
  string text = rec.GetValue(“Column Name”);
  int position = order.BinarySearch(text);
  if (position < 0)
  {
    order.Insert(-position - 1, text);
    unique.Add(text);
  }
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Hi.. @NicoSchertler Thanks...but implicit conversion is problematic..can u please explain how to do it...i need to access a method inside the "Record" also.

Comment: Also, why are you using `List<object>` when you're only ever adding text?

Comment: And how are we mean to know if `FilterItems` can be converted into a list, when we don't know *anything* about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear what you mean by "converting FilterItems into a list" when we don't know anything about it, but you could definitely consider sorting *after* you've got all the items, rather than as you go:

```
var strings = FilterItems.Select(record => record.GetValue("Column Name"))
                         .Distinct()
                         .OrderBy(x => x)
                         .ToList();
```

The use of `Distinct()` here will avoid sorting lots of equal items - it looks like you only want distinct items anyway.

If you want `unique` to be in the original order but `order` to be the same items, just sorted, you could use:

```
var unique = FilterItems.Select(record => record.GetValue("Column Name"))
                        .Distinct()
                        .ToList();
var order = unique.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```

Now `Distinct()` isn't guaranteed to preserve order - but it does so in the current implementation, and that's the most *natural* implementation, too.

Comment: Hi.. @Jon Skeet Thanks.. i mean can i directly bind the "FilterItem" collection into a list or any other ienumerable collection "Just asking"

Comment: @Arun: Sorry, I still don't understand what you mean at all - you're not being very clear, and you still haven't told us where FilterItem is coming from to start with.

Comment: ..In detail- "FilterItems" is from a Class named "FilteredCollection"... I can access record from the FilterItems using FilterItems[index]. It has records collection. I am asking if there any chance to directly bind this collection to a List or Ienumerable (using implicit or explicit conversion).

Comment: @Arun: That's not really in detail - we still don't even know the compile-time type of `FilterItems`. I also don't know what you mean by "directly bind this collection to a list" - it looks like it already *is* an `IEnumerable` of some kind. At this point however it sounds like it's really a different question from the main one here, so I suggest you ask a new question with a *lot* more information.